# Having a problem with namespaces and set_include_path() in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces, set-include-path

*C:\xampp\htdocs* contains **Controller.php** and **ApplicationHelper.php**.  *C:\xampp\htdocs\site* contains **index.php**.

Here is the error I am getting:

*Fatal error: Class 'site\controller\ApplicationHelper' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Controller.php on line 17*

I'm new to the whole namespaces business but I'm not 100% sure that thats whats behind it.  It just seems like its not finding *ApplicationHelper.php* even though I set the include path to look in that folder.  It works if I directly include *ApplicationHelper.php* in *Controller.php*.  Here is the (relevant) code:

**index.php**

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'C:\xampp\htdocs');

require('Controller.php');
\site\controller\Controller::run();
```

**Controller.php**

```
namespace site\controller;

class Controller {

    private $applicationHelper;
    private function __construct () {}

    static function run () {
        $instance = new Controller();
        $instance->init();
    }

    function init () {
        $applicationHelper = ApplicationHelper::instance();
        $applicationHelper->init();
    }

}
```

**ApplicationHelper.php**

```
namespace site\controller;

class ApplicationHelper {

    private static $instance;

    private function __construct () {}

    static function instance () {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    function init() {

    }

}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include ApplicationHelper.php or use an autoloader.

```
function __autoloader($class_name)
{
    include  $class_name . "php";
}
```

Comment: Would it be preferred to place that in index.php or each class that uses it?

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php